# Is it possible to change Google Meet configuration so users cannot disable microphone/video for example?

Tags: video, microphone, google-hangouts

I want to have a Google Meet meeting but I have to disallow users from manually disabling microphones/video in the calls. It is for a specific purpose and I need this feature.
The users cannot control microphones, only the admin should do it.

I do not find anything like that in the API.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** force the users to enable their microphones and/or cameras at all times during a meet.

Those options are specific to the users themselves and you cannot be the one to change them.